# Safe to delete System.map-* files in /boot?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, gentoo

I'm experimenting with generating some custom kernels using `genkernel`.

However, each iteration leaves a file in `/boot` called `System.map-genkernel-<arch>-<version>`.

Is it safe to rename and/or delete the `System.map-*` files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [System.map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map) file is mainly used to debug kernel crashes.  It's not actually necessary, but it's best to keep it around if you're going to use that kernel.  If you've decided you don't need that kernel, then it's safe to delete the corresponding map file.

If you're really low on disk space, you could compress the map files.  They aren't that big, so this won't save much space, but [bzip2](http://bzip.org/) will squeeze them down to about 25% of the original size.  Then you can uncompress one if you discover that you need it.

Comment: @cjm what if, after a certain time of continuous use (let's say, 2 weeks), I felt the kernel is stable and in no need of debugging. Is it safe to delete the `System.map` then?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: Why not delete it at the same time as deleting the kernel?

Comment: @jrtayloriv /boot is getting full

Comment: @Mikel I'm in a kernel 'paring down' loop, and I'd like to keep some prior revisions, just-in-case

Comment: I'm not saying don't keep one or two known good kernels, in fact I would suggest you do.  What I am suggesting is that when you delete a kernel, delete the map file for that kernel.  The map files are only about 1.8 MB.  Delete them if you have to, but if you've got more than two or three kernels, it might be time to delete a kernel and a System.map together.